# How to add panel as list item in Sencha touch 2.1?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to dynamically add list(with its items) to my container.
Instead of simple HTML template, I need list items to contain panel with a title bar, image & few more things.

To do this I am loading store data and within its callback creating List & array of items. Then I add items to the list and list to the container but end result is just last panel visible instead of sliding list of all panels.

Here is my code:

```
    var vLists = [];
    this.load({
        callback: function(records, operation, success) {
            var hccontainer = Ext.getCmp('hccontainer');
            this.each(function(record){
                var sid = 'styleStore'+record.get('id');
                var styleTemplate = eval('tpls.styleTemplate_' + record.get('id'));
                vLists.push({
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    scrollable: 'false',
                    layout: 'fit',
                    cid : record.get('id'),
                    ctype : record.get('type'),
                    cname : record.get('name'),
                    stid : sid,
                    tp : styleTemplate,
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype : 'titlebar',
                            title : record.get('name'),
                            docked : 'top',
                            cls : 'x-toolbar-transparent-top'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype : 'image',
                            src : record.get('image'),
                        }
                    ]
                });
            });
            //hccontainer.remove(Ext.getCmp('hc'), true);
            Ext.getCmp('hc').destroy();
            var hc1 = Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', {
                layout : 'fit',
                config: {
                    direction: 'horizontal',
                    id : 'hc'
                }
            });
            hc1.setItems(vLists);
            Ext.getCmp('hccontainer').add(hc1);
        },
        scope: this
    });
```

Is this right way to add items or I am missing something.

**PS** Instead of List if I use Carousel, this works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carousel is more of a layout component than List is. It doesn't look like you need to use a list, I don't see any handler for item taps for example. If you want to avoid using templates than you should not use a List. Instead just make a component with a list-like layout. I would use a container with a vbox layout, scretched horizontally and with a static height. You can then put whatever item configuration you want into this.

Comment: Thanks!I did the same, created a parent panel with vbox layout and then itreated over records to create array of panels and used panel.setItems(array of panels) to create the list.